# revision in POM.xml is causing to build child modules first and then parent module. Causing the target folder to delete

Tags: maven

Case 1: Referring version using revision in parent and child causing to execute parent module at last causing to delete target folder. Below is the sample pom.xml for parent and child

Parent pom.XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
   <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
   <groupId>com.org.parent</groupId>
   <artifactId>Services</artifactId>
   <version>${revision}</version>
   <packaging>pom</packaging>
   <name>parent</name>
   <description>Parent for Micro-Service API</description>
   <modules>
      <module>A</module>
      <module>B</module>
      <module>C</module>
      <module>D</module>
   </modules>
   <properties>
      <revision>1.0.0.25</revision>
      <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
      <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
      <java.version>1.8</java.version>
   </properties>
   <build>
      <plugins>
         <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
               <execution>
                  <id>copy-resource-one</id>
                  <phase>install</phase>
                  <goals>
                     <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                  </goals>
                  <configuration>
                     <outputDirectory>../target</outputDirectory>
                     <resources>
                        <resource>
                           <directory>/target</directory>
                        </resource>
                     </resources>
                  </configuration>
               </execution>
            </executions>
         </plugin>
      </plugins>
   </build>
</project>
```

Child pom.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
   <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
   <parent>
      <groupId>com.org.parent</groupId>
      <artifactId>Services</artifactId>
      <version>${revision}</version>
   </parent>
   <name>A</name>
   <description>A Service</description>
   <artifactId>A-service</artifactId>
   <packaging>jar</packaging>
   ..........
    ...........
    ...........
</project>
```

### Scanning for projects...

Reactor Build Order:

Child A
Child B
Child C
Child D
Parent
.........
...........

### Building parent 1.0.0.25

--- maven-clean-plugin:2.6.1:clean (default-clean) @ Services ---
Deleting C:\Users\akhilesh\git\JEE_M_SERVICES\Services\target

Case 2: If I remove revision in parent and child. Below is the build order.
Scanning for projects...
Reactor Build Order:

Parent
Child A
Child B
Child C
Child D

In this case since the parent target folder is deleting first. Jars are getting copied and available in parent target folder.

Expected: Has to use revision in parent child pom.xml's and should not delete target folder of parent at last (where child module jars are getting copied)

Comment: Which Maven version do you use? Apart from that I have my doubts that the configuration for maven-resources-plugin is correct nor does it belong into the parent nor should it being bound to install phase.

Comment: Apache Maven 3.5.3